# Can static websites be viewed without a server?

Tags: website, webserver

Really basic question, but I'm hoping to get some clarity here.

Let's say I have a static website with some html, some css and basic javascript. No web app to back it up. When testing the website locally, why do I need to run a web server to serve the content to the browser?

Is it because the relative paths in the URLs used in web pages are relative to the folder where the server is retrieving the content from and thus the various files included from the central HTML page can't quite get located on the file-system?

Comment: A good example of when a static website works without a webserver is when you save a website, either from a browser (`save page as`) or with a tool like httrack or wget. Those cases do most of the things you're asking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can static websites be viewed without a server?

Yes.

[image: No Surprise]

> When testing the website locally, why do I need to run a web server to serve the content to the browser?

You don't.

> Is it because the relative paths in the URLs used in web pages are relative to the folder where the server is retrieving the content from and thus the various files included from the central HTML page can't quite get located on the file-system?

No.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm aware that you can load any page on disk into your browser. However, will the local files linked in the html (e.g. <link href="css/mycss.css [...]/> or <script src="js/foo.js" [...]</script>) be referenced correctly? Is there a way to have the same URL work for both the way you showed, and when the same website is served through a server?

Comment: @glitch It should just work. Your browser's security settings might be getting in the way -- i.e. it might disallow access to local files from a website.

Comment: Great, thanks for taking the time to put that together :)

Comment: Back in ancient times before we added a CGI shopping cart, this was the way we tested for broken links. Xenu link sleuth on a local disk copy beat wasting time on the slow internet of the day. After implementing the shopping cart, we had to build an internal test server for running the CGI efficently for testing.

Comment: Actually interestingly enough this kind of script addition doesn't seem to work without a server, any clues why?
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @glitch `//` is protocol-relative, so I think you'll end up with `file://[whatever]/ajax.googleapis.com/...`. Which is what you're asking for.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Wonderful, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: It can work... Only if all your links are relative. For instance in `index.html` you need to reference the `style.css` file as `style.css`, while in `stuff/index.html` you need to reference it as `../style.css`. If you want to refer to it as `/style.css` in both places, though luck.

Comment: This answer is pat to the point of being wrong. You can absolutely put whole static websites together without serving them, but relative-vs-absolute links, as you suspect, @glitch, AND differences in how browsers treat local files (protocols differ, sandbagging happens) are why people use static *local* servers.

Comment: @Norswap  you wrote "Only if all your links are relative"  So are you claiming that you can't do absolute links like I recall maybe in internet explorer `file:///c|/blah/xyz.ext` ?

Comment: @barlop It might be possible on some browsers, especially older ones. Modern browsers (well at least Firefox, but I think he's not the only one) disallow accessing files that are not nested inside the directory in which the html file is located. This restriction can however be disabled via a configuration option in `about:config` IIRC.

Comment: @Norswap well if you know that then you shouldn't have made that comment, but best to leave your comment now otherwise the discussion turns to nonsense.

Answer (score 6):

Static websites can be viewed without a server, locally, simply by opening them up in a web browser, and you can do whole big websites this way if you want. But there are limitations and drawbacks, which is why people and systems use local servers for static websites.

One of the reasons you may be asking is because using many of the popular static site generators, like Jekyll, requires that you tell the system to `--serve` it (or similar), creating a local server for the static site. But if it's static, why do you need a server?

Here are a few reasons:

- only relative links are safe (`/` as a link to home is broken, as is referencing `/css/something.css`, since `/` is the root of your computer, not the site);
- relatedly, directory-level links fail (`blog/` shows the files under that directory, instead of looking for `blog/index.html` or similar);
- and browsers treat local files differently among themselves and between them and hosted files (Chrome limits AJAX calls, IE uses a different protocol from everyone else, etc.).

So, no, you don't need it, but you do need it if you want those things.